# Why do objects get removed from collection?

Tags: objects, outliner

Can anyone tell me why my objects get thrown under the "rig" node/null (sorry, not sure the correct term)?
You'll see in the before screengrab (left) that they were neatly sorted into collections, and now they're all thrown under "rig". I'm worried this will create problems down the pipe - is that a reasonable concern or is this just a display thing?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You parented the objects to rig.  The way the outliner works, parented objects appear as a tree underneath the parent.  If you select the arrow next to the icon by 'rig', it will open to show all of your parented objects, as you probably know.

It is possible to also have the parented objects in a second collection, but that tends to be more confusing then helpful, usually.

There's no harm in the organization, and it's how Blender has arranged the outliner since even before there were collections.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does this mean my collections which previously contained the objects are now void? Or is there an under-the-hood relationship somewhere?

Reason I ask is because I'm working with an engineer who was writing some code to toggle the visibility of those collections.

Comment: Follow up question:
Can I move the objects *back into* their respective collections without breaking the rig?

Comment: The previous collections aren't void, although they may be empty.  There's no under the hood relationship.  You can move the objects back to their original collections but that leads to the 'more confusing than helpful' state.  The manual way to do this is to open the rig, find the object, left click and hold control while dragging it back to its original collection.

Comment: Gotcha, and really, thank you so much for the info.

In order to get the renders I need I'm relying on toggling the Enable/Disable in Render for certain collections. I've lost that ability now that the objects no longer reside in those Collections. 

Since I have a need for the objects to be in the collections, would you consider that justification for moving them back? I'm sure you're cautioning me for a reason, but since I don't know the risks, I'm inclined to say my need for the control of the collections might outweigh the organization confusion. What do you think?